# Spring Integration MDC for Async Flow and Task Executors

Tags: spring-integration, mdc

I have a `flow` that starts with a `poller` and hands off the message to several `async` flows downstream using `task-executors` to execute in `parallel` for a given dataset. A downstream `aggregator` completes the flow and notifies the poller that the `flow` is complete.

I would like to `track` every execution of the poller by using `MDC` so that the `logs` can be mapped to a particular execution of the `flow`.

I started by adding `MDC` to the poller thread (using `Advice`), however with this approach there could be a couple of issues:

1. How do I stamp the `MDC` on the executor thread when the `async` hand off happens?
2. Since executor uses a a `thread pool`, do I need to clear the `MDC` before the `thread` returns to the pool? Will there be any side effects?

Another approach would be to add `MDC` to the `Message` header and set it manually on the new `thread` during the `async` handoff. *How to do that?* For example, if I turn on the `debug` logs, the `MDC` should be stamped right from the beginning of the new `thread` execution and not from the point where my logic starts in the `service activator`.
How to set this on the `task-executor` thread (and probably also remove before returning to the pool) using `XML` configuration? Something like an `MdcAwareThreadPoolExecutor` seen [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/common/util/ExecutorUtil.java#L144).
Also, I would not want the `MDC` logic to be spread across all the `async` handoff endpoints, may be there is some generic way to configure it?

Is there a better way to achieve this? Any known solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to track every execution of the poller by using MDC so that the logs can be mapped to a particular execution of the flow.

It is fully sound as "you would like to track the message journey in your flow". As you noticed there is the way to set some message header. So, why just don't map your logs by this specific header?

You can take a look into Message History pattern how to gather the whole path for the message, so then in logs you can track it back looking into message headers.

See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management.html#message-history

If you really still insist on the MDC, then you definitely need to take a look into some `MDCDelegatingExecutorDecorator. Some sample you can borrow from Spring Security and its` DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.0/reference/html5/#concurrency